# Apache Camel immediate read from SQS

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, amazon-sqs

I have very huge camel pipeline which starts from consuming message from SQS.
The time requires for whole process is vary. From 5 sec to 30 min, it is hard to guess here.

What I want to achieve:

1. Do not guess visibility timeout size, and just delete message from SQS as soon as message is consumed.

What I already tried:

1. Tried Camel option deleteAfterRead=true -> doesn't help, because as stated in the doc: **Delete message from SQS after it has been read (and processed by the route).** And I have huge pipeline. So processed requirement fails here.
2. Tried to increase visibility timeout, but as I stated, it is just a guessing game, and I want to develop more reliable solution.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

You should certainly NOT delete the message as soon as you consume it if you are not finished processing it because you will lose the message if your application crashes.

What you should do instead is **extend the visibility timeout manually** if you realize that your processing time gets close to the original visibility timeout. Not sure how you would implement it in Camel but we previously integrated into the default `springframework.cloud.aws.messaging`: https://github.com/Mercateo/sqs-utils

Comment: unfortunately it is not acceptable for my case. I really need to delete sqs message as soon as it is consumed

Comment: @AlexFaster why?  That simply does not make sense for a queuing system.

Comment: it is a part for manual reprocessing, we log in the database all processing steps and have logic which pickups the entity if it is not fully processed. So for us, the most important is to avoid reprocessing by any cost, because the pipeline is huge and requires a lot of processing power == money.

Comment: @luk2302 - To clarify, does setting the 'deleteAfterRead' in Camel to TRUE mean that the message is deleted as soon as it's read without waiting to see if it gets processed or not?

Comment: @SidharthRamesh I have no clue what camel does, sorry.

Comment: This does not answer the OP question. Instead, it is telling the OP to do something different.

Answer (score -1):

If, like the OP has stated, you don't mind about losing the messages in case e.g. of a server crash, there is a workaround consisting in sending the message to a `wireTap` and doing your processing there. This allows the main route to end early and a `deleteMessage` to be sent to the queue.

Another interesting, realted situation is that of an exception: if you have an exception handler in place and mark the exception as handled calling `handled(true)` on the `OnExceptionDefinition`, your message will be deleted too.

Comment: And then your server crashes and you have lost the messages, not a good idea. As I explained in my answer: don't delete message before you are done processing them.

Comment: I don't care about losing the messages, nor does the OP as he already told you. But you smarter than anyone, aren't you?